# No hay ningún elemento ViewData de tipo 'IEnumerable <SelectListItem>' que tenga la clave 'Conve'

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc, mvc

Estoy realizando un ajuste a una aplicación y al realizar un **UPDATE**. Me arroja el siguiente error:

> There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that
> has the key 'Conve'.

Mi **DropDownList** me carga los datos perfectamente pero cuando selecciono cualquiera de esa lista para utilizar su valor y cambiarlo por el valor que esta en mi BD arroja ese error

ANEXO Modelo: **TableAsign.cs**

```
public class TableAsign
{
    public long IdCliente { get; set; }
    public string nombre { get; set; }
   
}
```

Anexo Controlador: **MastController.cs**

```
 [Authorize]
    public ActionResult Asign_Conv(int idUsuario)
    {
        List<Models.TableAsign> lst = null;
        using (TPConveniosEntities db = new TPConveniosEntities())
        {
            lst = (from d in db.Cliente
                   orderby d.nombre
                   select new TableAsign
                   {
                       IdCliente = d.idCliente,
                       nombre = d.nombre
                   }).ToList();
        }
        List<SelectListItem> items = lst.ConvertAll(d =>
        {
            return new SelectListItem()
            {
                Text = d.nombre.ToString(),
                Value = d.IdCliente.ToString(),
                Selected = false
            };
        });

        ViewBag.items = items;

        using (TPConveniosEntities db = new TPConveniosEntities())
        {
            Usuario user = db.Usuario.FirstOrDefault(u => u.idUsuario == idUsuario);
            return View(user);
        }
     }
```

En Esta parte realiza el **UPDATE** y me parece que tiene que ver cuando traigo con mi variable **long** el value de mi **DropDownList**, el me arroja el error y luego cuando consulto mi BD veo que si realiza el **UPDATE** pero dándome ese error

```
    [Authorize]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Asign_Conv(FormCollection collection)
    {
        using (TPConveniosEntities contexto = new TPConveniosEntities())
        {
            var idUsuario = Convert.ToInt32(collection["IdUsuario"].Trim());
            Usuario user = contexto.Usuario.FirstOrDefault(u => u.idUsuario == idUsuario);

            var userName = collection["usuario"].Trim();
            long IdCliente = Convert.ToInt32(collection["Convenio"].Trim());

            user.userName = userName;
            user.idCliente = IdCliente;

            contexto.SaveChanges();
            return View(user);
        }
    }
```

ANEXO VISTA: **Asign_Conv.cshtml**

```
@using TPConvenios.App_Data;
@model Usuario
@{
    Layout = null;
    AjaxOptions ajaxOpciones = new AjaxOptions
    {
        UpdateTargetId = "cuerpoPopUpGenerico2",
        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
        OnSuccess = "OnSuccess_Asign",
        OnFailure = "OnFailure"
    };
    List<SelectListItem> items = (List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.items;
}
<div id="contenedor" style="margin: 15px 30px">
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Asign_Conv", "Mast", null, ajaxOpciones, new { id = "Asign_Conv" }))
    {  @Html.ValidationSummary(true);
     <input type="hidden" name="idUsuario" id="idUsuario" value="@(null != Model ? Model.idUsuario : 0)" />
     <p>
       Usuario:<input name="usuario" type="text" id="usuario" class="usuario" placeholder="Usuario" value="@(null != Model ? Model.userName : String.Empty)"/>
     </p>
     <p>
       Convenio:@Html.DropDownList("Convenio", items, "Seleccione el Convenio", new { @class = "form-control" })
     </p>
     <p id="bot">
     <input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" value="Asignar" class="botonNuevo" style="float: right" />
     </p>
    }
</div>
```

Agradezco la ayuda que puedan brindarme para solucionar este error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logre solventar mi problema trayéndome el código con que cargo mi DropdownList, y pegándolo al POST donde realiza **UPDATE**.

quedando de esta manera

```
    [Authorize]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Asign_Conv(FormCollection collection)
   {
        using (TPConveniosEntities contexto = new TPConveniosEntities())
        {
            var idUsuario = Convert.ToInt32(collection["IdUsuario"].Trim());
            Usuario user = contexto.Usuario.FirstOrDefault(u => u.idUsuario == idUsuario);

            var userName = collection["usuario"].Trim();
            long IDCliente = Convert.ToInt32(collection["Conve"].Trim());
           
            /*********** ESTO FUE LO QUE COPIE PARA QUE FUNCIONARA **********/
            
                List<Models.TableAsign> lst = null;
                using (TPConveniosEntities db = new TPConveniosEntities())
                {
                    lst = (from d in db.Cliente
                           orderby d.nombre
                           select new TableAsign
                           {
                               IdCliente = d.idCliente,
                               nombre = d.nombre
                           }).ToList();
                }
                List<SelectListItem> items = lst.ConvertAll(d =>
                {
                    return new SelectListItem()
                    {
                        Text = d.nombre.ToString(),
                        Value = d.IdCliente.ToString(),
                        Selected = false
                    };
                });
                ViewBag.items = items;

               /***************************   HASTA AQUI   **********************/
                user.userName = userName;
                user.idCliente = IDCliente;
                contexto.SaveChanges();
 
                return View(user);
            }
        }
```